# What does it mean that a laplacian of directed graph has full rank?

Tags: graph-theory, numerical-methods, directed-graphs, graph-laplacian, multigrid

Suppose we have a directed graph $G=(V, E)$ with $N=|V|$ nodes.
Define normalized graph laplacian as $L=I-AD^{-1}$ where $A$ is a adjacency matrix of $G$ and $D$ is a degree matrix of $G$.

I'm interested in solving $Lx=b$ with nonsymmetric LAMG method, called [NS-LAMG](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nla.2152).
NS-LAMG requires right null-space vector $v$ by solving $Lv=0$.
However, there exist a inverse of $L$ if $L$ is a full-ranked, which means $v=0$.
Therefore, it's impossible to solve the full-rank graph laplacian with NS-LAMG.
So I was wondering, what does it mean that a laplacian of directed graph has full rank?

[EDIT]:
suppose we have graph $G$ like below,

[image: graph]

so we have $$
    A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ], 
D =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$
then $$
L = I - AD^{-1} = 
\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$ and $rank(L)=4$

Comment: Downvoted for lack of source on the quote "laplacian of directed graph has full rank".

Answer (score 1):

The rank of the (normalized) Laplacian is never full, because the vector $(1,...,1)$ is always an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $0$ (which however solves your initial problem). See e.g.  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Properties).

For an interpretation of the multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ you can look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565504/multiplicity-of-0-eigenvalue-of-directed-graph-laplacian-matrix?rq=1)

Comment: I added an example of directed graph which has full rank in its laplacian

Comment: Ok, but I'm surprised by your definition of Laplacian. Usually (at least in the contexts I'm aware of, I cannot check in the article you linked), for directed graphswe consider the in- or out-degree matrix (e.g. in your examples, the in-degrees are $1,2,2,0$ and the out-degrees are $2,1,0,2$). If you use this in to define of Laplacian (as it is done in wikipedia, see also https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.02605.pdf), then the Laplacian matrix has rank $3=n-1$ in your example. (Notice that, since some degrees are $0$, you cannot invert the degree-matrix, so I considered the usual Laplacian $L=D-A$)

Comment: But that's the only case for undirected graph, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The usual definition of Laplacian is $L=D-A$ with $A$ the adjacency matrix and $D$ the degree matrix. For undirected graphs there is no ambiguity, for directed graphs you have to choose $D$ to be either the in- or out-degree matrix. In all cases, if $D$ is invertible you can consider the random walk Laplacian $L_{rw} = I -AD^{-1}$.

Comment: For directed graph one can observe that $A.(1,...,1)^t = (d_+(1),...,d_+(n))^t$ and  $(1,...,1)A = (d_-(1),...,d_+(n))$ , hence if D is the out-degree matrix $L.(1,...,1)^t = 0$ and if D is the in-degree matrix $(1,...,1)L=0$. In both cases the Laplacian has not full rank