# Generalized Rayleigh Quotient with Rank Deficient matrix $B$ in denominator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that the Rayleigh quotient problems usually deal with eigenvalue related problems, e.g., $\max_{x} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x}$, and the solution is related to the generalized eigenvalue problem $Ax = \lambda B x$. There are also some realy efficient algorithm to solve this type of problems, e.g., LOBPCG.

However, one of the main assumption of the above problem is that the matrix $B$ in the denominator must be positive definite, so that it is invertible. In my case, I am facing with a problem which may remove this assumption.

Specifically, Let $L$ be a Laplacian matrix, so that $L\mathbf{1}=0$. Now, I would like to solve the following Rayleigh quotient optimization problem:
$$
\max_{x}~  \frac{x^T A x}{x^TL^TLx}\\
s.t.~~ Lx \neq 0,
$$
where matrix $A$ and $L$ are all given. Clearly, if we remove the constraint $Lx\neq0$, this maximization can reach $+\infty$ by simply setting $x$ to $\mathbf{1}$ (in fact any $x \in Null(L)$ can work). I want to exclude this scenario, and add this constraint. Now, in this scenario, $B=L^TL$ is rank deficient, and the developed methods, e.g., LOBPCG, cannot be directly applied. My question is how can we solve the above problem (efficiently)?

My current attempt is to transform the constraint $Lx \neq 0$ into $ \Vert Lx \Vert = 1$. This is due to the fact that the Rayleigh quotient of $x$ is the same as $c \cdot x$ where $c$ is any scalar. As we have constrained that $Lx \neq 0$, we can assume the unit length of vector $Lx$. Consequently, we need to solve the following optimization:
$$
\max_{x}~  x^T A x\\
s.t.~~ x^TL^T L x = 1.
$$
However, this problem is still difficult, since it is not a convex optimization problem.

Can anyone give me some clues, references, papers, and algorithms of this problem? Many thanks ahead!

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a symmetric matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $L$ is the Laplacian of a connected graph so that its nullspace has dimension $1$, i.e. is completely spanned by $\mathbf 1$. Suppose that $L$ and $A$ have size $n \times n$.

Unless $\operatorname{null}(A) \supset \operatorname{null}(L)$, your constraint that $Lx = 0$ still leads to a situation where the objective function has no upper bound. In particular: given $x_0$ such that $Lx_0 \neq 0$ and $t > 0$, taking $x = x_0 + t \mathbf 1$ (or the normalized version of this vector, if you prefer) leads to
$$
\frac{x^TAx}{x^TLx} = \frac 1{x_0^TLx_0} 
\left(t^2 \mathbf 1^TA\mathbf 1 + tx_0^T(A + A^T)\mathbf 1 + x_0^TAx_0\right),
$$
which approaches $\pm \infty$ as $t \to \infty$ whenever $\mathbf 1^TA\mathbf 1 \neq 0$.

With that in mind, a more reasonable constraint might be $x \perp \mathbf 1$. The maximization with this constraint can be reduced to a more standard unconstrained maximization.

Let $V$ be a matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbf 1^\perp$, so that $V^TV = I_{n-1}$ and $VV^T$ is the projection onto this orthogonal complement. We note that for any $x \perp \mathbf 1$,
$$
\frac{x^TAx}{x^TLx} = \frac{(VV^Tx)^TA(VV^Tx)}{(VV^Tx)^TL(VV^Tx)} = \frac{(V^Tx)(V^TAV)(V^Tx)}{(V^Tx)(V^TLV)(V^Tx)} 
= \frac{y^T(V^TAV) y }{y^T(V^TLV)y},
$$
where $y = V^Tx$. Moreover, I claim that every $y \in \Bbb R^{n-1}$ can be expressed in the form $V^Tx$ for some $x \perp \mathbf 1$ (indeed, $y = V^T(Vy)$).

Thus, this problem can be reduced to $\max_y \frac{y^T(V^TAV) y }{y^T(V^TLV)y}$. If the nullspace of $L$ is spanned by $\mathbf 1$, then it follows that $V^TLV$ has full rank.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I realize the problem. The constraint $Lx\neq0$ is not enough to obtain a bounded maximization result.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I demonstrated in the first two paragraphs. However, if we are also given that $\operatorname{null}(L) \subseteq \operatorname{null}(A)$, then I think this constraint might lead to a bounded maximization.

Comment: Yes. That is right. One thing I am curious is that you said the dimension of $L$'s Null space is 1, if the corresponding graph is connected. In my case, the graph is directed, and $L$ may not be symmetric. If I still want to ensure the dimension of the directed graph's Laplacian $L$'s null space is 1, should we constrain the directed graph as a strongly connected graph or just weakly connected graph.

Comment: If $L$ is not symmetric, then the Rayleigh quotient maximization is no longer equivalent to the generalized eigenvalue problem. Also, I'm not sure about the rank of a directed Laplacian, but my guess is that weak connectivity is sufficient.

Comment: Oh. Since the Rayleigh quotient in the numerator is actually $x^TL^TLx$, in this case, it is still equivalent to a generalized eigenvalue problem. Though your answer is based on $x^TLx$, the value of this Rayleigh quotient is approaching infinity is still valid.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: To complete this question (answer), one can find the dimension of $L$'s null space (which is also that of $L^TL$) in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565504/multiplicity-of-0-eigenvalue-of-directed-graph-laplacian-matrix?rq=1), and the paper therein. Basically, when the directed graph is unilaterally connected (exists path either i->...->j or j->...->i, $\forall i, j$), we have $Null(L)=1$.